# Формирование отчета в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть программа для работы с бд, в которой присутствует функция добавления заказа. При добавлении заказа, нужно сформировать чек, который покажет все товары, которые заказал человек. Не могу никак понять, как это реализовать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть стоит посмотреть как реализована Northwind БД от Microsoft?
https://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/1091278/SeriateBlog1.png
Кстати, куда добавляется товар?

Comment: SODERJANIE_KONTRAKTA. Сказали, что там должны хранится все товары заказчика. Не могу никак въехать

Comment: Вы написали: "При добавлении товара, нужно сформировать чек...", при добавлении товара куда?

Comment: Прошу прощения, при добавлении заказа, а не товара. Исправил.